# Excluding specific pages from HTTPS in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to setup a codeigniter app to force HTTPS across all pages except one. However, I cannot get the rules to only redirect if the user is **not** on the page in question.

The page that should be excluded has the following URL's:

- http://mydomain.com/kpi/reports/67
- http://mydomain.com/kpi/reports/67/overview/2013-02-01/2013-02-28
- http://mydomain.com/index.php?/kpi/reports/67
- http://mydomain.com/index.php?/kpi/reports/67/overview/2013-02-01/2013-02-28

The number **67** and the dates can all change in the URL's above hence the user of regular expressions below.

I have tested the regular expressions and they seem to match the URL's fine. However, the htaccess just seems to redirect it to https:// anyway.

My .htaccess file is as follows...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Disallow access to system dir
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Disallow access to application dir
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Force https when not on overview report
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php\?/kpi/reports/?([0-9]+)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php\?/kpi/reports/?([0-9]+)/overview/?([0-9]+)-?([0-9]+)-?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)-?([0-9]+)-?([0-9]+)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kpi/reports/?([0-9]+)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/kpi/reports/?([0-9]+)/overview/?([0-9]+)-?([0-9]+)-?([0-9]+)/?([0-9]+)-?([0-9]+)-?([0-9]+)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

    #If not a valid file, redirect request through index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will do what you need:

```
#Force https when not on overview report
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !kpi/reports/[0-9]+/?$                     [NC]  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !kpi/reports/[0-9]+/overview/[^/]+/[^/]+/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !kpi/reports/[0-9]+/?$                     [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !kpi/reports/[0-9]+/overview/[^/]+/[^/]+/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}           [R=302,L]

#If not a valid file, redirect request through index.php
```

Replace all lines between the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a couple problems with your suggestion. The dates can change so these would have to be a regular expression. Also, this also selects anything beginning with "kpi/reports/89" for example. This means that "kpi/reports/89/graphs" is also selected which I don't want - I only want "kpi/reports/89/overview" selected when the longer URL is used.

Comment: Thanks! That works great. Could you tell me how I would force those matched pages to display on http (non-SSL) if they are accessed with a https:// prefix. My htaccess to far is at https://gist.github.com/dangreaves/5117595. You can see my additions under "Force http on overview report". The rules currently have zero effect.

Comment: I figured it out. Just essentially used your rules in reverse. Thanks for you help!